# Haskell & Qt : how to display a text when a button is clicked?

Tags: qt, haskell, hsqml

I am trying to create a program which displays "hello" when one clicks on a button, using Qt and haskell (with HsQML).

PLEASE GO DIRECTLY TO THE LAST UPDATE : you will see the last error I have made :-)

I've got a base which works but in my own program I already have an error

```
/home/lowley/Documents/haskell/Qt/exemple-2.hs: line 13, column 5:
parse error on input `skey'
/home/lowley/Documents/haskell/Qt/exemple-2.hs: line 13, column 5:
Warning: Parse error: Last statement in a do-block must be an
expression
Found:
  main = do
    state <- newIORef $ T.pack ""
>     skey <- newSignalKey
      clazz <- newClass [
        defPropertySigRO' "my_label" skey (\_ ->)
```

here is my program:

```
module Main where

import Graphics.QML
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Exception
import Data.IORef
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T

main :: IO ()
main = do
    state <- newIORef $ T.pack ""
    skey <- newSignalKey
    clazz <- newClass [
        defPropertySigRO' "my_label" skey (\_ ->
            readIORef state),
        defMethod' "sayHello" (\obj txt->
            writeIORef state $ T.pack txt
            fireSignal skey obj
            return ())]
    ctx <- newObject clazz ()
    runEngineLoop defaultEngineConfig {
        initialDocument = fileDocument "exemple2.qml",
        contextObject = Just $ anyObjRef ctx}
```

and here is the QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

Item {
    height: 266
    Button {
        id: bouton
        x: 278
        y: 77
        text: qsTr("click me!")
        onClicked: sayHello("Hello!!")
    }

    Text {
        x: 166
        y: 147
        width: 309
        height: 87
        text: my_label
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        font.pixelSize: 76
    }

}
```

for information, here is an example which works, it is in the same directory and is also compiled with sublime text:

HS file:

```
module Main where

import Graphics.QML
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Exception
import Data.IORef
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T

main :: IO ()
main = do
    state <- newIORef $ T.pack ""
    skey <- newSignalKey
    clazz <- newClass [
        defPropertySigRO' "result" skey (\_ ->
            readIORef state),
        defMethod' "factorial" (\obj txt -> do
            let n = read $ T.unpack txt :: Integer
            writeIORef state $ T.pack "Working..."
            fireSignal skey obj
            forkIO $ do
                let out = T.take 1000 . T.pack . show $ product [1..n]
                evaluate out
                writeIORef state out
                fireSignal skey obj
            return ())]
    ctx <- newObject clazz ()
    runEngineLoop defaultEngineConfig {
        initialDocument = fileDocument "factorial2.qml",
        contextObject = Just $ anyObjRef ctx}
```

QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Column {
    height: 300;
    TextInput {
        id: input; width: 300; font.pixelSize: 30; focus: true;
    }
    Rectangle {
        color: "red"; width: childrenRect.width; height: childrenRect.height;
        Text {
            width: 300; font.pixelSize: 30;
            text: "Calculate Factorial"; color: "white";
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent;
            onClicked: factorial(input.text);
        }
    }
    Text {
        width: 300; wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere; font.pixelSize: 30;
        text: result;
    }
}
```

If you can see a difference between them, I am highly interested.

UPDATE:
now that I changed all the spaces by tabs, I am faced to an other error :

```
Couldn't match expected type `(skv0
                                 -> tt0 -> Graphics.QML.Objects.SignalValueParams skv0)
                                -> SignalKey p0 -> ObjRef () -> (a0 -> m0 a0) -> () -> Text'
              with actual type `Text'
  The function `T.pack' is applied to six arguments,
  but its type `String -> Text' has only one
  In the second argument of `($)', namely
    `T.pack "hello" fireSignal skey obj return ()'
  In the expression:
    writeIORef state $ T.pack "hello" fireSignal skey obj return ()
```

I don't understand why ghc complains about pack which would applied to 6 arguments...

UPDATE:
this code:

```
module Main where

import Graphics.QML
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Exception
import Data.IORef
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T

main :: IO ()
main = do
    state <- newIORef $ T.pack ""
    skey <- newSignalKey
    clazz <- newClass [
        defPropertySigRO' "my_label" skey (\_ -> readIORef state),
        defMethod' "sayHello" (\obj txt -> do
            writeIORef state $ T.pack txt
            fireSignal skey obj
            return ())]
    ctx <- newObject clazz ()
    runEngineLoop defaultEngineConfig {
        initialDocument = fileDocument "exemple2.qml",
        contextObject = Just $ anyObjRef ctx}
```

leads to this error, still not understandable:

```
exemple-2.hs:16:17:
    Couldn't match type `MarshalMode Char ICanGetFrom ()' with `Yes'
    In the expression:
      defMethod'
        "sayHello"
        (\ obj txt
           -> do { writeIORef state $ T.pack txt;
                   fireSignal skey obj;
                   return () })
    In the first argument of `newClass', namely
      `[defPropertySigRO' "my_label" skey (\ _ -> readIORef state),
        defMethod'
          "sayHello"
          (\ obj txt
             -> do { writeIORef state $ T.pack txt;
                     .... })]'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      clazz <- newClass
                 [defPropertySigRO' "my_label" skey (\ _ -> readIORef state),
                  defMethod'
                    "sayHello"
                    (\ obj txt
                       -> do { writeIORef state $ T.pack txt;
                               .... })]
```

EDIT : new code, new error message...

code:

```
module Main where

import Graphics.QML
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Exception
import Data.IORef
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T

main :: IO ()
main = do
    state <- newIORef $ T.pack ""
    skey <- newSignalKey
    clazz <- newClass [
        defPropertySigRO' "my_label" skey (\_ -> readIORef state),
        defMethod' "sayHello" (\obj txt -> do
            writeIORef state txt
            fireSignal skey obj
            return ())]
    ctx <- newObject clazz ()
    runEngineLoop defaultEngineConfig {
        initialDocument = fileDocument "exemple2.qml",
        contextObject = Just $ anyObjRef ctx}
```

error message:

```
Build FAILED

/home/lowley/Documents/haskell/Qt/exemple-2.hs: line 13, column 10:
  No instance for (SignalSuffix (IO a0))
    arising from a use of `newSignalKey'
  The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
  Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
  Note: there is a potential instance available:
    instance SignalSuffix (IO ()) -- Defined in `Graphics.QML.Objects'
  Possible fix:
    add an instance declaration for (SignalSuffix (IO a0))
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: skey <- newSignalKey
  In the expression:
    do { state <- newIORef $ T.pack "";
         skey <- newSignalKey;
         clazz <- newClass
                    [defPropertySigRO' "my_label" skey (\ _ -> readIORef state),
                     defMethod' "sayHello" (\ obj txt -> ...)];
         ctx <- newObject clazz ();
         .... }
  In an equation for `main':
      main
        = do { state <- newIORef $ T.pack "";
               skey <- newSignalKey;
               clazz <- newClass
                          [defPropertySigRO' "my_label" skey (\ _ -> ...), ....];
               .... }
```

Comment: This is simply a Haskell parse error, nothing to do with QT (so if you QT code is broken as well, I wouldn't know). As you can see in the error, it believe that the indendation is wrong: "    state <- ..." vs ">     skey <-...". If the indentation looks write to you, its probably because you are mixing tabs and spaces - pick one or the other, you must be consistent in your choice.

Comment: ok, that was the problem.

Comment: For the 2nd error: GHC complains because you *have* applied it to 6 arguments. Replace `(\obj txt->` with `(\obj txt-> do`.

Comment: thanks! but I've got another error!

Comment: @lolveley: If you have a new problem, ask a new question. :-) If you want, link to it in the comment section of this question.

Comment: ok! Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847550/button-click-a-message-does-not-appear-in-a-haskell-program