# Qt : button click => a message should appear in a haskell program

Tags: qt, ubuntu, haskell, sublimetext3

I try to create a program which displays a text when a button is clicked, using haskell & Qt, on ubuntu using sublime text 3.
But apparently there is a problem when defining the signal key (the key which will identify the signal called when the button is clicked).
Moreover, it's hard to find a documentation about HsQML, the binding joining haskell & Qt.

code:

```
module Main where

import Graphics.QML
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Exception
import Data.IORef
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T

    main :: IO ()
    main = do
        state <- newIORef $ T.pack ""
        skey <- newSignalKey
        clazz <- newClass [
            defPropertySigRO' "my_label" skey (\_ -> readIORef state),
            defMethod' "sayHello" (\obj txt -> do
                writeIORef state txt
                fireSignal skey obj
                return ())]
        ctx <- newObject clazz ()
        runEngineLoop defaultEngineConfig {
            initialDocument = fileDocument "exemple2.qml",
            contextObject = Just $ anyObjRef ctx}
```

error message:

```
Build FAILED

/home/lowley/Documents/haskell/Qt/exemple-2.hs: line 13, column 10:
  No instance for (SignalSuffix (IO a0))
    arising from a use of `newSignalKey'
  The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
  Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
  Note: there is a potential instance available:
    instance SignalSuffix (IO ()) -- Defined in `Graphics.QML.Objects'
  Possible fix:
    add an instance declaration for (SignalSuffix (IO a0))
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: skey <- newSignalKey
  In the expression:
    do { state <- newIORef $ T.pack "";
         skey <- newSignalKey;
         clazz <- newClass
                    [defPropertySigRO' "my_label" skey (\ _ -> readIORef state),
                     defMethod' "sayHello" (\ obj txt -> ...)];
         ctx <- newObject clazz ();
         .... }
  In an equation for `main':
      main
        = do { state <- newIORef $ T.pack "";
               skey <- newSignalKey;
               clazz <- newClass
                          [defPropertySigRO' "my_label" skey (\ _ -> ...), ....];
               .... }
```

SOLVED!
but I wonder why this program can be compiled without the above error:

```
module Main where

import Graphics.QML
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Exception
import Data.IORef
import qualified Data.Text as T

main :: IO ()
main = do
    state <- newIORef $ T.pack ""
    skey <- newSignalKey
    clazz <- newClass [
        defPropertySigRO' "result" skey (\_ ->
            readIORef state),
        defMethod' "factorial" (\obj txt -> do
            let n = read $ T.unpack txt :: Integer
            writeIORef state $ T.pack "Working..."
            fireSignal skey obj
            forkIO $ do
                let out = T.take 1000 . T.pack . show $ product [1..n]
                evaluate out
                writeIORef state out
                fireSignal skey obj
            return ())]
    ctx <- newObject clazz ()
    runEngineLoop defaultEngineConfig {
        initialDocument = fileDocument "factorial2.qml",
        contextObject = Just $ anyObjRef ctx}
```

Comment: Not that I advocate using it, and it's not an answer to your question, but there's also a qt package for haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There error tells you that GHC doesn't know what type the signal created by [`newSignalKey`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsqml-0.3.4.0/docs/Graphics-QML-Objects.html#v:newSignalKey) should have (`newSignalKey :: SignalSuffix p => IO (SignalKey p)`. GHC does not know what `p` should be, since you don't specify it). Adding an explicit type signature like this:

```
skey <- newSignalKey :: IO (SignalKey (IO ()))
```

should fix the error that you are seeing.

Ok, so now why does it work in the second example? To understand that, we have to look at what GHC knows and what it can determine about the type of `skey`.

In the first example and in the second example, `skey` is used as follows:

```
do
  ...
  fireSignal skey obj
  ...
```

Because `fireSignal :: SignalKey p -> ObjRef () -> p` (simplified type, the full type of `fireSignal` is more general), GHC knows that `p` must be `IO something`, because it is used in a context where an `IO something` action is expected (as part of a do block in `IO`). It does not know what `something` is though, since the return value of that `IO` action is never used. So it is left with `skey :: SignalKey (IO something)`, and rightly reports an error that `something` is ambiguous (it doesn't know what type `something` should be).

In the second example, skey is however also used in the following pattern:

```
forkIO $ do
  ...
  fireSignal skey obj
```

Since `forkIO` expects an `IO` action that returns a value of type `()`, GHC now knows that `fireSignal skey obj :: IO ()` (so in this case, it knows that `something` must be `()`). That means that `p` is no longer ambiguous, it must be `IO ()`.

Comment: thanks, it works! but please have a look at my edit.

Comment: nice! give me a sec and I'll edit the answer to explain the typechecking process more deeply in this case